# delete record in jqgrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to delete a record in `jqgrid`.
For this I have the image and when the user clicks on this the record is getting deleted.

But I want to show the `confirm` box and when true then only the record should get deleted.

So any one can tell how to call javascript in `jqgrid`.

My jqgrid is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
        url: 'AddFilterGrid.aspx?Show=ViewFilter',
        datatype: "json",
        id: "FilterName",
        colNames: ["SubCategory", "Filter", 'Delete', 'Edit'],
        colModel: [{
                name: 'CategoryName',
                index: 'CategoryName',
                width: 150,
                align: 'left',
                sortable: true,
                sorttype: 'text'
            }, {
                name: 'FilterName',
                index: 'FilterName',
                width: 150,
                align: 'left',
                sortable: true,
                sorttype: 'text'
            }, {
                name: 'f',
                index: 'f',
                width: 100,
                align: "center",
                formatter: 'showlink',
                formatter: formateadorLinkDelete
            }, {
                name: 'FilterId',
                index: 'FilterId',
                width: 100,
                align: "center",
                formatter: 'showlink',
                formatter: formateadorLinkEdit
            },

        ],
        height: 280,
        width: 650,
        //autowidth: true,
        mtype: "GET",
        pager: '#plist47',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        repeatitems: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: 'FilterName',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        gridview: true,
        imgpath: '/Scripts/themes/redmond/images'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a column with a delete button, give your button an attribute with the id, so you can post that id to delete it.

do a post to your delete controller

```
$.post('url/delete/$(this).val("deletid")', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

@ edit: create a delete link in one of your colums, with class="delete" and deleteid="the id"
you can create a confirm popup box:

```
$(function(){
    $(.delete).foreach(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Submit":  function(){
                             $.post('url/delete/$(this).val("deletid")', function(data) {

                                //find your tr and hide it
                                $(this).parent().parent.... .hide();
                             });
                           };
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });  
});
```